# Testcafe tests fails from azure devops

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Tests that are run from Azure devops build pipeline fails sporadically with the below error.

```
Error: Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser connections. This can be caused by network issues or remote device failure.
    at BrowserSet._waitConnectionsOpened (D:\a\1\s\src\test\Testcafe\node_modules\testcafe\src\runner\browser-set.ts:91:30)
    at D:\a\1\s\src\test\Testcafe\node_modules\testcafe\src\runner\browser-set.ts:114:35
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at Bootstrapper._getBrowserConnections (D:\a\1\s\src\test\Testcafe\node_modules\testcafe\src\runner\bootstrapper.ts:216:16)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at Bootstrapper._bootstrapParallel (D:\a\1\s\src\test\Testcafe\node_modules\testcafe\src\runner\bootstrapper.ts:392:38)
    at Bootstrapper.createRunnableConfiguration (D:\a\1\s\src\test\Testcafe\node_modules\testcafe\src\runner\bootstrapper.ts:425:42)
```

Versions and settings used for running the test.

Testcafe: 1.8.8

Testrunner:

```
return runner
  .browsers(['chrome:headless'])
  .concurrency(1)
  .screenshots('./screenshots', { takeOnFails: true })
  .reporter('junit', stream)
  .src(['./*tests/*.js'])
  .run({
    skipJsErrors: true,
    skipUncaughtErrors: true,
    quarantineMode: false,
    selectorTimeout: 15000,
    assertionTimeout: 15000,
    pageLoadTimeout: 5000,
    speed: 1,
    debugOnFail: false,
    stopOnFirstFail: false
  })
```

Azure pipeline yaml

```
steps:
- script: |    
      node testRunner.js
```

Comment: This error means that TestCafe failed to start the browser due to some reason. Likely, this issue is caused by the environment. Could you please share an example that can be used to reproduce the problem? Ideally, you can create a free GitHub repo with the free Azure Pipelines plan. At least, please share your `azure-pipelines.yml`.

Comment: the test is run from command line task with node and the testrunner file. added the yaml to the post.

Comment: I created a sample repository and cannot reproduce the issue: [https://github.com/AndreyBelym/testcafe-example-azure](https://github.com/AndreyBelym/testcafe-example-azure). I also noticed that my builds use the Ubuntu agent, while the issue in the original post contains Windows directory separators. Could you please ensure that the provided YAML configuration is complete? I can make some additional attempts to reproduce it, but it will be better if you share a similar repository that can be used to reproduce the problem.